# Privilégios de usuários(2)

Tags: php, html

Bom,estou com um exercício para faculdade que é a criação de um blog.Pode conter 4 usuários diferentes: Usuário(só lê post e comenta) Redator(Cria os posts e gerencia comentários) ADM(gerencia todos os posts e comentários) ADM Geral controle total do sistema (criar,editar.excluir qualquer elemento incluindo usuários e permissões)

Para criar post,alterar permissões etc, é necessário uma barra de navegação no site,minha dúvida é: Como posso fazer aparecer as opções correspondentes na barra para cada usuário?

Cada usuário tem um numero correspondente: o usuário = 1 , redator = 2...
Este código abaixo é do meu login, eu gostaria de fazer o privilégio neste momento,quando o usuário logar,ele ira para a página principal e terá as opções que correspondem á seu nível.Além disso, a barra de navegação,estilo dos botões,das div's,devem estar num arquivo separado.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["new"]="limitado";
require_once('BdClass.php');
if(isset($_GET['login']) and isset($_GET['senha'])){
$objBd = new bd();
$objBd->conecta_mysql();
$param= array();
array_push($param, $_GET['login']);
array_push($param, $_GET['senha']);
$sql="SELECT nome,senha,id,tipo from usuario where nome=? and senha=? and ativo = 1;";
$result=$objBd->exec($sql,'ss',$param);
$valor=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if(isset($valor['nome'])){
    $_SESSION["nome"]=$valor['nome'];
    $_SESSION["senha"]=$valor['senha'];
    $_SESSION["id"]=$valor['id'];
    $_SESSION["tipo"]=$valor['tipo'];
    $_SESSION["ativo"] = 1;
    header("location:1.html");
}
else{
     echo "<script>alert('Se cadastre antes para logar no site');</script>";
 }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
    <title>INICIO</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li><a href="Pagi.php">Oh...Blooog!</a></li>
  <<li><a href="Login.php">Cadastro</a></li>
</ul>
<form method="GET" action="Login.php">
    <label>Nome: </label>
    <div><input type="text" name="login" value="">
    </div>
    <label>Senha: </label>
    <div><input type="password" name="senha">
    </div>
    <div><input type="submit" name="ok">
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Duplicou porquê?

Comment: Se a sua dúvida é um desdobramento da anterior, ponha o link da anterior citando-a e ponha aqui só os pontos diferenciais relevantes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cria uma estrutura de switch, e salva em um array todas as funções de cada permissão do 'usuario' no final do switch cria um foreach de cada permissão para o usuario

Comment: Em qual parte deste código?

Comment: o melhor local seria verificar e colocar dentro do array de funçoes no topo da página (após a query), e para fazer o foreach seria onde queira colocar os inputs, links, etc, pois irá dar um echo de cada função do usuario